# Guardar en una nueva lista

Tags: java

tengo un pequeño método que va comparando los objetos y quiero que si en la comparacion == false lo guarde y si es true rompa el bucle for.

```
public static void metodo(ArrayList<Objeto> listaObjt) {
        ArrayList<Objeto> lista = new ArrayList();
        Objeto objeto1, objeto2;
        boolean cierto;
        int a = 0;
        while(a!=listaObjt.size()) {
            for(int i = 0; i<listaObjt.size();i++) {
                objeto1 = (Objeto) listaObjt.get(i);
                objeto2 = (Objeto) listaObjt.get(a);
                cierto = Objeto.esCierto(objeto1, objeto2);
                if(cierto == false) {
                    //guardarlo en la lista
                }else {
                    break;//salir e incrementar a, volver a comprobar
                }

            } a++;
        }
    }
```

Lo que pasa es que hasta que no es cierto lo guarda en la lista, y quiero que compruebe hasta que termine de recorrer la lista. ¿Sabríais como lo puedo poner para que lo haga bien?
También se me ocurrió poner un if (cierto == true) break; pero no sabría como guardarlo si es false. Solo quiero guardar el objeto2 si al terminar de comprobar todos los objetos de la lista es false

Comment: a ver tu vas recorriendo la lista y compruebas si es vedadero o falso y lo agrega pero no puedes primero recorrer y verificar todo y luego agregarlo. de toda manera expicate unm poco mejor e intento ayiudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero de todo, no es recomendable usar un break dentro de un for, ya que des de la programación estructurada, romper un bucle des de dentro y hacerlo terminar antes de que se termine su condición de iteración no es recomendable.

Según entiendo por tu pregunta, Quieres guardar el objeto2, si después de recorrer toda la lista, la condición sigue siendo falsa, entonces lo quieres insertar, sino no.

Para hacerlo, puedes usar una variable booleana para gestionar lo que quieres de la siguiente forma:

```
public static void metodo(ArrayList<Objeto> listaObjt) {
    ArrayList<Objeto> lista = new ArrayList();
    Objeto objeto1, objeto2;
    boolean cierto;
    int a = 0;
    while(a!=listaObjt.size()) {
        cierto = false;
        for(int i = 0; i<listaObjt.size() && !cierto;i++) {
            objeto1 = (Objeto) listaObjt.get(i);
            objeto2 = (Objeto) listaObjt.get(a);
            if(Objeto.esCierto(objeto1, objeto2)) {
                cierto = true;
            }
        }
        if(!cierto){
            //guardarlo en la lista
        }
        a++;
    }
}
```

De esta forma, lo que hacemos es tenemos una variable booleana como control, en este caso la variable cierto y la variable la vamos a inicializar a false, de tal forma que dentro del for vamos a ir evaluando tu funcion de Objeto.esCierto(objeto1,objeto2), y solo modificaremos el valor de cierto, cuando la función devuelva true. Es decir, si al final del bucle, ninguna vez ha sido true, la variable seguira en el valor inicial que era falso.

**Edit**

Cuando tu evaluas un if, tienes dos maneras de hacerlo:

```
boolean ejemplo = true;
if(ejemplo == true){
    //se cumple la condición
}else{
    //no se cumple
}

boolean ejemplo = true;
if(ejemplo){
    //se cumple
}else{
    //no se cumple
}
```

Como puedes ver en este pequeño ejemplo, los 2 casos funcionan igual, es decir tu cuando pones una condición en un if, si estas evaluando una variable de tipo boolean, es lo mismo poner if(variable == true) que poner if(variable) ya que la variable propia ya es de tipo boolean, la puedes evaluar directamente.

Si miramos a la solución, la parte que no entiendes del if, Objeto.esCierto() devuelve un valor de tipo boolean, es decir puedo hacer 2 cosas guardarlo en una variable y evaluarla o evaluar directamente lo que devuelve la función. Se suele utilizar mas la segunda opción ya que es más rapido y comodo de escribir.

**Edit 2**

Para comparar objetos en Java y en general, no puedes usar ==, el == lo que hace es comparar si los dos objetos están apuntando a la misma posición de memoria, basicamente te miran si el objeto es el mismo en memoria, no si son iguales.

Tu función esCierto deberia ser de la siguiente forma:

```
public boolean esCierto(Object obj1, Object obj2){
    return obj1.equals(obj2);
}
```

Usando el metodo equals de las librerías de java para evaluar si dos objetos son iguales.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es el if que utilizas, if(Objeto.esCierto(objeto1,objeto2)), esCierto es un método booleano, e if un condicional, si ese método devuelve true cierto cambia, es lo que entiendo, pero si no cambia, el otro condicional !cierto, siempre sería true, no?

Comment: He editado la respuesta a ver si lo ves mas claro.

Comment: Lo he probado y no me guarda nada en la lista.

Comment: Puedes modificar la pregunta y poner un ejemplo, es decir que valores de entrada hay, que valores de salida. Que valores debería añadir a la lista, para poder entender mas el funcionamiento exacto del programa.

Comment: Podría ser por que tengo que si objeto1 == objeto2 return true? Podría poner en el condicional que me pones un && u ||? Y como los objetos son de la misma lista coinciden

Comment: No estoy seguro de entenderte del todo con lo que dices && y ||, mira mi edición a ver si asi te funciona, para comparar objetos en java no debes usar ==, sino deberias usar object.equals() de las librerías de java.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106633/discussion-between-pol-vilarrasa-and-jorge-velazquez).

Comment: *romper un bucle des de dentro y hacerlo terminar antes de que se termine su condición de iteración no es recomendable..* Eso no es del todo cierto. Usar la sentencia `break` adentro de la condicional, es sumamente recomendable porque hará romper el ciclo y de este modo, no hará iteraciones innecesarias. En tu primer código, cuando esta condición se cumpla: `Objeto.esCierto(objeto1, objeto2)` la variable `cierto` valdrá `true` y siempre seguirá teniendo el mismo valor... Por lo tanto, no necesitas iterar más, ahí es un buen uso del `break` y de paso, aumenta la eficiencia del código.

Comment: @PolVilarrasa Otro ejemplo sería cuando quieres buscar un objeto en una lista enlazada. Si encontraste el objeto en el centro, ya no necesitas iterar más, simplemente, rompes el ciclo.

Comment: Es cierto que hay veces donde no necesitas iterar mas en el codigo, pero ahi por ejemplo podrias cambiar la condición de iteración, la manera correcta de romper un bucle es con la condición de iteración, no con un break dentro del bucle.

Comment: @MrDave1999 ya he editado mi respuesta, esa seria la forma correcta de salir del bucle y evitar dar mas vueltas, lo de salir con un break no es la forma buena.

Comment: Eso ya es subjetivo. *Si el `break` existe, es por algo..* Ninguna de las dos alternativas es incorrecta. Si fuera "incorrecta", tendría fallas y en este caso, no lo es.